# YTPlyaer YouTube full-screen display is not available

Tags: youtube-api, ytplayer

I have embedded a YouTube player using YTPlyaer ver 3.2.9

On desktop and android devices everything works perfectly fine,
On IOS the firescreen button is missing

This is the init code im using:

```
    var video_source = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/somecode";

    this.youtube_player_element.YTPlayer({
        containment: 'self',
        videoURL:video_source,
        ratio:'4/3',
        optimizeDisplay: true,
        showYTLogo: false,
        addRaster: false,
        showAnnotations: false,

    });
```

Comment: What did you mean by "firescreen"? If you meant the full screen button, then apparently, it is an [issue only for iOS 10 and above](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/245).

Comment: Yes i meant full-screen, so there is no fix for that ? you have any other recommendation on how to handle this problem ?